# login passport com email e password e passando id user como parametro no get

Tags: node.js, react, login

Estou criando um site em React, NodeJS e MongoDB para um projeto do curso e estou com uma dúvida no meu login.

Meu login solicita email e senha ao user, porém eu criei meu método no front que chama o `get` baseado no `id` do user pois é a variável que eu uso no `aggregation` com meu database pra buscar o seu `Roster` de trabalho. Coloquei um `id` de teste pra verificar e funciona bem, porém preciso saber como pegar esse valor de `id` do meu backend.

Seria necessario fazer outro `aggregate`?

Segue o código no meu frontend:

```html
<button onClick={getRosterByUser}>roster</button>
```

```
const getRosterByUser = () => {
  Axios({
    method: 'GET',
    withCredentials: true,
    url: `http://localhost:4000/roster/5fd778b02e61463ea46eadf9`
  }).then((res) => {
    setRoster(res.data);
    console.log(res.data);
  });
};
```

Código do backend:

```
app.get('/roster/:_id', (req, res) => {
  const _id = req.params._id;

  Roster.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $match: {
          userId: objectId(_id)
        }
      },
      { $unwind: '$week' },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'store',
          localField: 'week.store_id',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'user_roster'
        }
      },
      {
        $project: {
          week: 1,
          roster: {
            $arrayElemAt: ['$user_roster', 0]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    function (err, doc) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(doc);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Se você quiser levar o id do back end para o front normalmente se usa o template ejs para isso ou outros métodos também, mais como está usando react recomendo ver alguns template para trocar informações entre eles.